# Is there a reference data set for ridge regression?

Tags: dataset, research, ridge-regression

In order to test an algorithm, I am looking for a reference data set for ridge regression in research papers. Kind of like the equivalent of MNIST but for regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Boston house data set.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

boston = load_boston()
boston_df = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns = boston.feature_names)
boston_df.insert(0, 'Price', boston.target)
```

Then you can use Ridge Regression to predict the housing prices from the other features in the data set.

Source: https://towardsdatascience.com/ridge-and-lasso-regression-a-complete-guide-with-python-scikit-learn-e20e34bcbf0b

Comment: Thanks you very much but there is not enough data in this dataset, I was thinking more of a number of data in the same range as mnist

Comment: You might try looking through some of the datasets here: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html